# Create a locked PDF file with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have searched all over the net for a solution as to how I can create a locked PDF file using PHP.
Can anyone help with this?

Note: I am not looking at password protecting the PDF. Just want it so that the average punter cannot edit the PDF file.

Comment: Locked PDF in the senss you have mentioned it not to be password protected?

Answer (score 0):

If you use FPDF to generate your PDF files, you can protect it like so:

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script37.php